# Write to a file in PL/SQL without spools or utl_file

Tags: sql, plsql, sqlplus, spool, utl-file

Trying to create an output file through a procedure but am unable to modify the init.ora to allow for utl_file_dir or create directory. Is there another way to accomplish this without creating a table and doing a simple spool, this unfortunately, is out the question, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You will need access to `init.ora` to get this done the nice way through Oracle.

The only other option I can think of is the use of a Java procedure to do the file writing. I couldn't find any special requirements you need to have set to use that. Read up on the subject [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225/chthree.htm).

Comment: to piggy back off the article you linked to, this one was helpful as well. https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/file-handling-from-plsql which I only found because I knew what to search for from your answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you have access to sqlplus then add dbms_output.put_line messages to the code and run it in sqlplus. Before running type:

```
spool <filename you want>
```

then

```
spool off
```

to close the file and stop writing.

Either that or using Java could be an option but you will need additional privileges to access the file system and compile a java method on the db.

You should really be given access to a directory on the filesystem. Speak to a dba and if there is a business requirement you should be able to make it happen.

Comment: OP stated he couldn't use spool.

Comment: OP needs to speak to his dba - to summarize, he can't change anything about his environment and he can't run sqlplus through a client. What exactly can he do!